# How do I reset the IPMI interface on my Power8 server?

Tags: powerpc, ipmi

I have a problem with our Power8 box. I can no longer use the IPMI interface - every command I issue even simple read only queries like "chassis status" result in the following output:

```
$ /opt/local/bin/ipmitool -I lanplus -H 192.168.70.147 -P admin chassis status
Error in open session response message : insufficient resources for session

Error: Unable to establish IPMI v2 / RMCP+ session
Error sending Chassis Status command
```

The issue with this is that I can no longer access the SOL interface. Any ideas how I get the box out of this state? I've tried power cycling - next idea is to reset to factory defaults.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access to IPMI is mutually exclusive between the PowerVM and PowerKVM enabled modes.

As seen, IPMI will work just fine in the OPAL hypervisor mode, PowerVM mode uses a different firmware load.

There's an emerging page for [IPMI considerations](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/wikis/home?lang=en#!/wiki/W51a7ffcf4dfd_4b40_9d82_446ebc23c550/page/IPMI%20considerations) over on the DeveloperWorks realm.

There's also some information on IPMI in the [PowerKVM Redbook](http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/redpieces/pdfs/sg248231.pdf).